# What is a transaction in terms of Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

The following information is [from official site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/storage/) :

I should pay $0.0036 per 100,000 transactions for Blobs.

What is a `transaction`? That's mean that if my algorithm works with `4kb` blocks instead of `8kb` then I will need to pay two times more?

And what about container creation/deletion? Is it one transaction?

Comment: That is explained in the site you linked, perhaps in the same line you copied the example from `We charge $0.0036 per 100,000 transactions for Block Blobs. Transactions include both read and write operations to storage.`

Comment: Are you asking for something *other* than normal read/write operations? Eg deletion, renaming, copying? Whether changing blob attributes is also charged?

Comment: You only copied half the paragraph to the question, and the answer to your question was contained within the other half the paragraph.  Plus, this isn't a programming question as much as a question about a service provided by a 3rd party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Storage is managed through a REST API. Whenever you perform a REST API operation (say create table, delete table, create container, delete container etc.), that constitutes a transaction. However not all transactions are billable. For example, if the transaction fails authentication then it is not a billable transaction.

> That's mean that if my algorithm works with 4kb blocks instead of 8kb
>   then I will need to pay two times more?

That's correct. Because you're performing twice the number of `Put Block` REST API operations.

I would recommend reading up this blog post by Azure Storage Team where it has been explained in an excellent way: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/07/08/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity/.